# four grids arrangement using css

Tags: html, css

When four div grids are used, and the content size of the table 2 is increased,the table 3 comes in line with that of table 4 ,resulting in a long gap between table 1 and 3. Is there any way to bring the responsive content increment and decrement of table combinations 1,3,5.. and 2,4,6... so as the eliminate the gap between tables 3 and 4 as

```
pg hf1 |
pg hf2

table1 |
table2

table1 |
table2

table1 |
table4

table3 |
table4
```

where pg hf is one half of the page i.e col-xs-6.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container container-fluid">
  <h1>Offsetting Columns</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgray; margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px; overflow-wrap:break-word ">table1fffff ffffff fffff fffff fffff </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px; overflow-wrap:break-word">table2  yyyyyyy fffffff ffffffy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy  yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyy</div>

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgreen; margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px">table3</div>

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightblue; margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px">table4</div>

     <!--<div class="row" style="background-color:lavender;"></div>-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdcL7o38/4/

Comment: so when theyre 50/50 you want table 3 to be right underneath table 1?

Comment: yes i guess you got the question right

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the CSS Grid Layout.

Please find the below code.

**Type1: one on one**

Plunker link for runnable code-
https://jsfiddle.net/s0qqhnu7/
[image: image1]

```
<body>
       <div class="container container-fluid">
          <h1>Offsetting Columns</h1>
          <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgray; margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px; overflow-wrap:break-word ">table1fffff ffffff fffff fffff fffff </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px; overflow-wrap:break-word">table2  yyyyyyy fffffff ffffffy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy  yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyy</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgreen; margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px">table3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightblue; margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px">table4</div>
          </div>
          <!--<div class="row" style="background-color:lavender;"></div>-->
       </div>
    </body>
```

**Type2:**
**One left and one right**

Plunker link https://jsfiddle.net/wt70cfcj/

```
<body>
   <div class="container container-fluid">
      <h1>Offsetting Columns</h1>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgray; margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px; overflow-wrap:break-word ">table1fffff ffffff fffff fffff fffff </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
         <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px; overflow-wrap:break-word">table2  yyyyyyy fffffff ffffffy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy  yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyyyy yyyyy</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgreen; margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px">table3</div>
         <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
         <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightblue; margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px">table4</div>
      </div>
      <!--<div class="row" style="background-color:lavender;"></div>-->
   </div>
</body>
```

[image: image2]

Comment: Type1 is surely not the answer for my case. My question is not to align them in a row but to remove all the spaces and gaps among the tables in your type 2 output.

Comment: Actually As I understand your question I responsed.